# How to run ScalaTest tests in the SAME class in PARALLEL

Tags: sbt, scalatest

On an environment with

- scala 2.12
- sbt 1.1.4
- scalatest 3.0.5

I'm not able to run tests in the same class in a parallel because it looks like SBT will run in a parallel way every class, not the test in the same class.

e.g.

- I have a class called `TestA` in `qa.parallelism package`. This class contains two tests called `test1` and `test2`.
- I have another class called `TestB` in `qa.parallelism package` that contains a test called `test1`.

if I run

```
testOnly qa.parallelism.*
```

by log I understand that TestA.test1 and TestB.test1 was executed simultaneously,

but if I run

```
testOnly qa.parallelism.TestA
```

that contains two tests (`test1` and `test2`), I understand that `test2` will be executed at the end of `test1`.

Is there a way to run simultaneously every test of a single class or I should create a class for every single test?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[`ParallelTestExecution`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.ParallelTestExecution) docs state default ScalaTest behaviour is to:

> ...run different suites in parallel, but the tests of any one suite
>   sequentially.

However, mixing in `ParallelTestExecution` trait enables tests within the same class to be run in parallel. For example,

```
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers, ParallelTestExecution}

class HelloSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with ParallelTestExecution {
  "The Hello object" should "say hello 1" in {
    println("1")
    Hello.greeting should be ("hello")
  }

  it should "say hello 2" in {
    println("2")
    Hello.greeting should be ("hello")
  }

  it should "say hello 3" in {
    println("3")
    Hello.greeting should be ("hello")
  }
}
```

outputs different orderings of printlns on different `sbt test` executions.

Comment: Resolution above will allow you to run tests in parallel, but it will limit number of concurrent tests to 2*number of your cpu cores. If you are interested in running all tests at the same time (and it is above that limit) you may look at my resolution for similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169343/limit-scalatest-parallel-execution-thread-number