# Scala sbt tests with Junit not running in Parallel

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, parallel-testing

I've some integration tests written in Scala sbt which uses Junit5. I want to run the tests within the suite in parallel, however unable to do so.

This is how my code looks like:

```
trait IntegrationTestBase extends AnyFunSpec with Matchers with OptionValues with Inside
  with Inspectors with ScalaFutures with BeforeAndAfter with BeforeAndAfterAll with LazyLogging
```

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class TestClass extends IntegrationTestBase with ParallelTestExecution {
  override protected def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    super.beforeAll()
    ...
  }

  override protected def afterAll(): Unit = {
    super.afterAll()
    ...
  }

  describe("Test Group 1") {
    it("some test should pass") {
      ...
    }
  }

  describe("Test Group 2") {
    it("some different test should pass") {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Currently, Test Group 2 execution starts only after Test Group 1 is completed. I want the Test Group 1 and Test Group 2 to run in parallel. What am I missing here?

Tried adding this configuration in sbt file - `Test / testForkedParallel := true` but no change in result.

Also tried to configure the [parallel execution guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/?t=7#writing-tests-parallel-execution) from junit5 by creating the `junit-platform.properties` with configuration:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = concurrent

junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy = fixed
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism = 6
```

But this didn't work as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit scalatest parallel execution thread number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169343/limit-scalatest-parallel-execution-thread-number)

Comment: @GastónSchabas It did not work. It started the tests in parallel but then the execution was kind of weird where it didn't wait for the `Thread.sleep(time)` and the test is also getting marked as Passed before even the execution got completed.

Comment: I'm preferably looking for some native solution from Junit5 or Scala-test here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run ScalaTest tests in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752681/run-scalatest-tests-in-parallel)

Comment: tl;dr `testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-P")` should help

Comment: Tried this as well, no change. :/